# Ubuntu 22.0 screen and icons refresh every second

Tags: drivers, graphics

I upgraded my Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. I have this issue. My screen and everything refreshes every second and I can't do anything.

[image: My Screen]

Results of `sudo lshw -c video` :

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
```

Comment: A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Your question lacks any info that could be used to assist you. I do not even see a valid version. Please EDIT the question and add some detail. For example a new install? An upgrade?